# Видимость элемента TreeView (WPF)

Tags: wpf, binding

Для TreeView задан шаблон данных. Выглядит он примерно так (некоторые поля убрал для наглядности):

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TreeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,Path=Vars}">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFCBBEBE" BorderThickness="1" Padding="0,2,0,1">
        <WrapPanel Margin="0,1,0,2">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5,0" FontSize="18" Width="900"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Border>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="#FFCBBEBE" BorderThickness="1" Padding="0,2,0,1" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visible}">
                <WrapPanel Margin="0,1,0,2">
                    <TextBlock Width="350" Height="30" Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="18"></TextBlock>                      
                </WrapPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

[image: Образец]

Как видно из кода и рисунка, дерево имеет два уровня. Корневые элементы привязаны к свойству Name источника данных. Вложенные элементы также имеют свойство Name и некоторые другие, которые я здесь не показал. Проблема заключается в том, что видимость вложенного элемента тоже должна подхватываться из источника данных. В примере я показал видимость элемента Border, но при этом на месте удалённых элементов остаётся пустое пространство, как показано на рисунке. Как указать видимость самого TreeViewItem?

Comment: Для `TreeViewItem` у вас есть `IsExpanded`. Скажите лучше, чего вы хотите добиться; может быть, `TreeView` — неподходящий инструмент.

Comment: Нужно управлять видимостью элемента, выделенного красным. На рисунке деактивирован элемент, находящийся между элементом "Температура дутья" и "Температура холодного дутья". Поскольку сейчас я управляю видимостью не TreeViewItem, а Border, на его месте образовалась белая полоса.

IsExpanded может скрыть все дочерние элементы, а я управляю видимостью каждого элемента. Поэтому он не подходит.

Comment: Но даже если использовать IsExpanded, я не знаю как к нему обратиться. Ситуация аналогична описанной.
UPD. То есть нужно перенести Visibility="{Binding Path=Visible}" из элемента Boder в TreeViewItem.

Comment: @Alouette: А зачем вам управлять видимостью на уровне View? Это неправильно. У вас просто не должно быть этого элемента в `ItemsSource` и всё. Работайте на уровне ViewModel.

Comment: Такое техническое задание. Нужно управлять видимостью всех параметров как при отображении на форме, так и в отчёте.
А удалять элемент из ItemsSource не следует, так как каждый параметр участвует в расчёте.